# Terminal Problem - No such file or directory... What should I do?

Tags: terminal, homebrew

bit of a newbie. I unistalled homebrew today as well as the hidden files. However, every time i go to the terminal, this pops up:

```
Last login: Sat Apr  2 11:28:28 on ttys001
/Users/dylangrech/.zprofile:1: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/Users/dylangrech/.zprofile:2: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/Users/dylangrech/.zprofile:3: no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
dylangrech@Dylans-Air ~ %
```

Is it normal? How can I fix it? TIA!

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer usage; [Superuser](https://superuser.com) and [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) are better places to ask about things like this (and you should search for similar questions before asking). However, from the error message it's clear that you need to edit your .zprofile (/Users/dylangrech/.zprofile), and probably remove lines 1-3.

Answer (score 0):

Once cleanup the `homebrew` references in `/Users/dylangrech/.zprofile`, you wont see those errors.